# Creating a UWP application with MVVM Light and PCL

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mvvm, uwp

I'm starting a Windows UWP project using MVVM and it was my intention to put my ViewModels into a PCL project so that I can make use of Mocking when writing unit tests. However I'm used to using MVVM Light framework and it seems that it is no longer supporting PCL projects. If I want to continue creating my ViewModels in a PCL project in the future, will I have to go without MVVM Light or would it be recommended not use a PCL (and thus Mocking in my Unit tests)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were changes to NuGet that do not allow code files to be added to a solution via NuGet.  You can add the mvvmlight libraries only package and add the view models to the PCL.

Comment: If I want to have a view model inherit from Mvvm Light's ViewModelBase though, can I still do that?

Comment: @user1970028 you can. The Nuget package you're going to want is [this one called MvvmLightLibs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLightLibs/).

Comment: Actually if I try to install MvvmLightLibs I get a couple of Nuget errors like:


MvvmLightLibs 5.2.0 is not compatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0 (win7-x86)

Comment: @user1970028 you are getting this error because your PCL project targeting ASP.NET Core, but MvvmLightLibs 5.2.0 does not support it. To remove this target, open properties of PCL project, and on the tab Library you should see Targeting section. Just clear checkbox near ASP.NET Core and save. Also you can select for example: .NETFramework 4.5, Windows 8.0, Windows 8.1 or Windows Universal 10. Then you can use MvvmLightLibs 5.2.0 or 5.3.0 without any problems.